# changing span css throws undefined function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to loop through all child spans in a div and change their css on interval, like so:

[image]

`console.log(container[j]);` gives:

```
<span class=​"char7">​r​</span>​
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**JS:**

```
function callback() {
 //#palindromeRun div contains value "racecar"
    $("#palindromeRun").lettering(); //split each letter in input into separate span
    $("#palindromeRun span").each(function (i, v) {
        container.push(v);
    });
    i = 0;
    j = container.length-1;
        myInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (i === j) {
                window.clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
            console.log(container[j]);
            container[i].css({"color" : "green"});
            container[j].css({"color" : "green"});      
            i++;
            j--;

        }, 1000);
}
```

So my question is, if `container` array contains spans, like `<span class=​"char7">​r​</span>`, why would it say `undefined is not a function`?

---

EDIT: [updated JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/huqudolu/6/)

Comment: Post a fiddle or your full markup.

Comment: It could be because `.css()` is a jQuery method and you are not invoking it through `$`.

Comment: The function inside setInterval is acting like call back function. you should bind it.

Comment: @shaunakde fiddle posted

Comment: looks to me like it works perfectly from that jsbin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `v` you are pushing into your container array is not a jQuery object it is a DOM element and as such, no .css() method exists for it. You would either need to access it as `$(container[j]).css({"color":"green"});` or by `container[j].style.color = "green"`

Comment: @Growler In your jsBin, it is failing because TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#palindromeRun").lettering()') You haven't defined your lettering function therefor it isn't even making it down to the code where you attempt to change the span color. It fails at your invocation of the non-existent lettering function.

Comment: then how is it possible that `<span class=​"char7">​r​</span>​` is generated if `jsLettering` isn't being run? That `r` is the first character of `racecar`, which has been split into spans

Comment: @Growler I'm going off of what is in your jsBin, not on your actual implementation, and nowhere in the jsBin are you including jsLettering. That is the error I'm seeing in the console and without getting past that error I can't debug any further. If you can get that script in your jsBin, I'd be happy to have another look.

Comment: PS - @Growler - Really like the South Beach piece on your site. It captures the light well.

Comment: I appreciate that :) So it's splitting the letters into their own separate spans. I'm just stumped why `container[i].css({"color" : "green"});` isn't changing the colors as the `setInterval` iterates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55406/discussion-between-growler-and-mifi79).

Comment: Did you change container[i] to $(container[i])? Remember, the element passed in the each function is the native DOM object not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

### [Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/pipeveda/1/edit)

The problem was in `$("#palindromeRun").lettering();`.

You don't have the plugin file included for this. Comment out this line, it works without error.

```
function callback1() {
    $("#palindromeRun").lettering();
    $("#palindromeRun span").each(function (i, v) {

        container.push(v);
    });
    i = 0;
    j = container.length - 1;
    //console.log(container[j]);
    myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (i === j) {
            window.clearInterval(myInterval);
            container = [];
        }
        console.log(i + ' : ' + j + ' : len:' + container.length);
        $(container[i]).css({
            "color": "red"
        });
        $(container[j]).css({
            "color": "red"
        });


        i++;
        j--;
        notrunning = true;
    }, 1000);

}
```

1. use `$(container[i]).css({"color" : "red"});` and not `container[i].css({"color" : "red"});`
2. `container = [];` clear container `if(i==j)`, else the elements will keep adding to previous array version.

---

For lettering to work, you need to include reference to this.

```
<script src="http://letteringjs.com/js/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know. I was able to get jsLetter plugin working. Your demo isn't changing the colors of the letters

Comment: @Growler, check the latest code version. It is working. **[JSBIN Link](http://jsbin.com/pipeveda/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

try using the following :

```
console.log(container[j].toString());
```

Because you are pushing each span as object in the container array.

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
 $(container[j]).css({"color":"green"});
```